# Materialize carousel Arrows Not Working On Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, carousel, materialize

I have a full-width carousel using materialize with some arrows signaling next and previous carousel elements.  Works great on desktop but they are not working on mobile.  I have been researching it and supposedly there is a bug (no surprise) with this element that they have not covered up.  I was wondering if anyone has ran into this similar problem and knew a way around it?  The following code worked for one individual just not for me:

```
function setupEvents() {
    if (typeof window.ontouchstart !== 'undefined') {
        view.on('touchstart.carousel', tap);
        view.on('touchmove.carousel', drag);
        view.on('touchend.carousel', release);
    }
    view.on('mousedown.carousel', tap);
    view.on('mousemove.carousel', drag);
    view.on('mouseup.carousel', release);
    view.on('mouseleave.carousel', release);
    view.on('click.carousel', click);
}
```

On mobile it can be dragged just not able to be initiated by clicking the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **replace** that code snippet in `materialize.js (0.100.2)`

host the materialize files locally so you can customize it.

search for this implementation in it.

```
function setupEvents() {
    if (typeof window.ontouchstart !== 'undefined') {
        view.on('touchstart.carousel', tap);
        view.on('touchmove.carousel', drag);
        view.on('touchend.carousel', release);
    }
    view.on('mousedown.carousel', tap);
    view.on('mousemove.carousel', drag);
    view.on('mouseup.carousel', release);
    view.on('mouseleave.carousel', release);
    view.on('click.carousel', click);
}
```

***replace the above code ^ with the code given below:***

```
function setupEvents() {
    if (typeof window.ontouchstart !== 'undefined') {
       view[0].addEventListener('touchstart', tap);
       view[0].addEventListener('touchmove', drag);
       view[0].addEventListener('touchend', release);
    }
    view[0].addEventListener('mousedown', tap);
    view[0].addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
    view[0].addEventListener('mouseup', release);
    view[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', release);
    view[0].addEventListener('click', click);
}
```

Everything should now be working as expected.

Reference & thanks to `ddiaz914` for the fix. [github issue #5052](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5052)

Comment: Thank you Ajay.  I have always just gone the CDN route with my front end CSS frameworks.  I am young in the industry so obviously I will learn and adapt as necessary.  I like using materialize and obviously there are bugs all the time so it may have to be something I move over to for manipulations like this one... Also 1 more question... Do you know if there was any major changes in the new 1.0 version with carousels?  I was using old CDNs in this project and wanted to upgrade to 1.0 but it completely breaks the carousel and the slides don't show up.

Comment: I am using the carousel sliders and have cards on each slide and they just do not show up... the code looks identical and initializations don't seem to have changed... I didn't know if it was just the combination of components that was making it freak out or what.

Comment: @D-Man they got a lot of changes in 1.0, for example highlight is "jQuery is no longer a dependency in 1.0!" so it's bound to break your existing projects, you might be using another css framework(eg. bootstrap etc.) along with materialize which could cause conflicts.
Further changes can be read here : [Materialize: To 1.0 and Beyond](https://medium.com/@materializecss/materialize-to-1-0-and-beyond-e0233b8ac15)